# Restructuring a string with regex

Tags: r, regex

Within a variable in a df, there could be a string 'Type 1' that I would like to extract into another variable as 'type_1', or 'Type 2' into 'type_2', or 'Type 3' into 'type_3' and so on.
Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: To see the gsub function, e.g. , `gsub("Type (.*)","type_\\1",str1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` in base R.

Extract everything before a space and turn it to lower case replacing space with an underscore.

```
x <- c('Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3')
sub('(.*)\\s', '\\L\\1_', x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "type_1" "type_2" "type_3"
```

`(.*)` is a capture group which captures everything until a whitespace (`\\s`). `\\L` turn the captured value (`\\1`) to lower case.

Comment: Hi thanks for this! can you please explain what each part in the regex means for the pattern and replacement arguments?

Comment: I added some explanation for the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `tolower()`,

```
tolower(c("Type_1", "TYpe_2", "TYPe_3"))

[1] "type_1" "type_2" "type_3"
```